# Cannot hide "li" element using knockout JS

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

```
<li data-icon="false" id="row2_li2" data-bind="visible: $root.isCompletionMode()">
    <a href="">
       <h2>
           <span data-bind="text: $root.LABELS.LABEL1"/>
       </h2>
       <aside class="ui-li-aside">
             <select
                    data-bind="
                    value: $root.there.are.some.value.here
                    .......
                    ">
             </select>
       </aside>
   </a>
</li>
```

Above is my code and I'm trying to hide the li element with id="row2_li2" using

```
 $.mobile.activePage.find('#row2_li2').hide();
```

but when it renders, the inspect element is showing only "style" and it was not hidden at all.

```
<li data-icon="false" id="row2_li2" data-bind="visible: $root.isCompletionMode()" style="">
                <a href="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-a" data-theme="a">
                    <h2>
```

that jquery code seems working on li elements without the data-bind attribute.

Comment: Any reason for using react and knockout combined? because, knockout could be again evaulating $root.isCompletionMode() and returning true and hence you are seeing the component

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets from $root.IsCompletionMode

You don't need the brackets when using knockout bindings,
you use them when you need the value of an observable in a statement like:

```
 <li data-icon="false" id="row2_li2" data-bind="visible: $root.isCompletionMode() == true">
```

Comment: is there a possibility that isCompletionMode is a function?